# can appcelerator use NSUserDefaults on iphone?

Tags: nsuserdefaults, iphone-sdk-3.1, appcelerator

I'm trying out the version 1.2 appcelerator and wanted to use the NSUserDefaults with it...  has anyone tried that before??

I can find it in the docs...   :{

thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Titanium.App.Properties: http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.2/Titanium.App.Properties